# Why is my version of Euler's Method not working?

Tags: code-review, coding-style, code

I am creating Euler's method for $\frac{dw}{dt}=(3-w)(w+1)$ for $\Delta t=0.5$ from $0\le t \le 3$. I tried the following.

```
S[w_, t_] := (3 - w)*(w + 1)
S[0, 0] := 3
h = 0.5
S[w + 1, t] == w + h*S[w, t]
P[m_] := S[m, m]
Table[P[x], {x, 0, 3/(0.5)}]
```

Which gives

```
out[321]= 0.5
out[322]= {3, 3, 3, 0, -5, -12, -21}
```

However, I doubt this is the correct answer. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define the recursive increment. (I assume in your code `S[w + 1, t] == w + h*S[w, t]` is related to that.)

```
F[w_, t_, h_] := w + h*S[w, t]

{h, n} = {0.1, 20};
pnts = NestList[{#1[[1]] + h, F[#1[[2]], #1[[1]], h]} &, {0, 0}, n];

ListLinePlot[pnts, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Here we verify.

```
sol = First[
  Flatten[f /. 
    DSolve[{f'[t] == Evaluate[S[f[t], t]], f[0] == 0}, f, t]]]

(* Function[{t}, (3 (-1 + E^(4 t)))/(3 + E^(4 t))] *)

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{pnts[[All, 1]], sol /@ pnts[[All, 1]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried using your code `S[w_, t_] := (3 - w)*(w + 1)` `F[w_, t_, h_] := w + h*S[w, t]`

`{h, n} = {0.1, 20};`
`pnts = NestList[{#1[[1]] + h, F[#1[[2]], #1[[1]], h]} &, {0, 0}, n];`

`ListLinePlot[pnts, PlotRange -> All]` but instead get `ListLinePlot::lpn
General::stop
NestList::intnm
ListLinePlot::lpn
NestList::intnm
NestList::intnm
Set::altno
NestList::intnm
NestList::intnm` How do we fix this?

Comment: I have no problems running this code : `S[w_, t_] := (3 - w)*(w + 1);
F[w_, t_, h_] := w + h*S[w, t];
{h, n} = {0.1, 20}; pnts = 
 NestList[{#1[[1]] + h, F[#1[[2]], #1[[1]], h]} &, {0, 0}, 
  n]; ListLinePlot[pnts, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: Never mind, I made a careless mistake : |